# Does anybody know how I can find the headers for IOS5 Iphones/ipod. Jailbreak development

Tags: ios, header, jailbreak, statusbar, tweak

I would like to class dump my iPod Touch 4 if that is possible so I can find the IOS 5 headers for a tweak I am making. If somebody dosn't already know the header name for the statsubar?

Please help!
This is for jailbroken iPods and jailbreak development

Answer (score 0):

The header name for the status bar is `UIStatusBar.h` inside `UIKit.framework`. https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/ has a list of all the iOS 5 frameworks, and you can see the contents of `UIStatusBar.h`  at https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIStatusBar.h.

Comment: Thank you very much, but if I wanted to place something, like an icon on the statusbar, can I then use this header. Or?

Comment: Cause I'v heard that the header for the satusbar is also SBStatusBarDataManager, or could this maybe me a header for another IOS, like IOS4?

Comment: You can use `UIStatusBarServer`'s `-addStatusBarItem:` method (https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIStatusBarServer.h) to add a `UIStatusBarItem` (https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIStatusBarItem.h).

Comment: Basically, the thing I want to do is to just to add another clock onto the StatusBar? Do you have any idea at all on how I am supposed to do that? Also, do you think doing that, could be a difficult task for me? Do I have to know advanced programming and such?

Comment: Yes, it counts as very advanced. I've just been trying and can't work out how to get it to work. Thing is, you're on your own, as there is no documentation. You have to experiment with various combinations and methods until it works.

Comment: Darn! Well, I have a partner that I'm working with, and the to be honest I don't think it's the worlds hardest thing to do. But, listen, since you're a pretty good objective C programmer, there was something I have very long been curious about? When you for example would like to copy something to another place, like the statusbar, but you don't know what code you have to use to accomplish that. What do you do then, how do you look for the code, and where do you find it? or is that something that every objective C programmer should know?

Comment: Well the code behind the status bar isn't available (it's been compiled), so you can't see what has been done by Apple. All you have is the headers, and so for private APIs, you have to look at where different classes are referenced to piece together how you work with the APIs. Then to get it to work it's just trial and improvement.

Comment: Weird... Otherwise, how much programming experience have you with Objective C, adn how long have you been writing it? Extra, how long did you use to learn it? What do you accomplish with class dump?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8220/discussion-between-jrtc27-and-luka-momcilovic)

Comment: Isn't chat only for those eith 145 points or so? If not, then the obly possibilty for a cha ust be now, cause I'm going on vacation for a week tomorpw and Am back next Sunday!

Comment: 20 rep or more for chat. This sort of discussion is a bit off-topic and so is better in chat.

Comment: Why is the chat removed? I can't access it? Please start a new chat, I have some questions more I'd like to ask?
Do you know the StatusBar header for IOS5?

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8499/ios-5-private-headers To be honest I don't know any more than I've already said, so you might be best trying to get other answers. Sorry!